# C++ Can I use OpenGL framebuffer without seeing the window?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I have an OpenGL application, that displays a camera frame with some 3d elements rendered on top of it. 
What i am trying to do is use openGL to combine the frame and elements, but then display the image with OpenCv, and not show the OpenGL window. Is this possible?

The current code is:

```
int main()
{
 // Init GLUT window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

  // Create GLUT window
    glutInitWindowSize(wWnd, hWnd);
    glutCreateWindow("Mapping");

 // Initialize OpenGL
    int res = initGL();
    if (res != 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize OpenGL" << std::endl;       
        return -1;
    }

....

}
```

Where the `init` function is:

```
int initGL() {

    // Init glew after window has been created
    glewInit();
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    // Create and Register OpenGL Texture for Image (RGBA -- 4channels)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &imageTex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, imageTex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, wWnd, hWnd, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    cudaError_t err1 = cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&cuda_gl_ressource, imageTex, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard);
    if (err1 != cudaError::cudaSuccess) return -1;

    // Create GLSL Shaders for Mesh and Image
    shader_mesh = new Shader((GLchar*) MESH_VERTEX_SHADER, (GLchar*) MESH_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    shMVPMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_mesh->getProgramId(), "u_mvpMatrix");
    shColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_mesh->getProgramId(), "u_color");
    shader_image = new Shader((GLchar*) IMAGE_VERTEX_SHADER, (GLchar*) IMAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    texID = glGetUniformLocation(shader_image->getProgramId(), "texImage");

    // Create Frame Buffer for offline rendering
    // Here we render the composition of the image and the projection of the mesh on top of it in a texture (using FBO - Frame Buffer Object)
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    // Generate a render texture (which will contain the image and mesh in wireframe overlay)
    glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);

    // Give an empty image to OpenGL ( the last "0" as pointer )
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, wWnd, hWnd, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Set "renderedTexture" as our color attachment #0
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);

    // Set the list of draw buffers.
    GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

    // Always check that our framebuffer is ok
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        std::cout << "invalid FrameBuffer" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // Generate the Quad for showing the image in a full viewport
    static const GLfloat g_quad_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};

    // Color of wireframe (soft blue)
    vertices_color.r = 0.35f;
    vertices_color.g = 0.65f;
    vertices_color.b = 0.95f;

    // Generate a buffer to handle vertices for the GLSL shader
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_vb);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vb);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_quad_vertex_buffer_data), g_quad_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);

    return 0;
}
```

I am fine with grabbing the framebuffer and converting it to a cv::mat, and i have that working. My problem is, i cannot seem to run the application without the GL Window.
If I comment out the `glutCreateWindow` line, the `init` fails.

Is it possible to run openGL in the background, without showing the window? 
Thank you.

Comment: `glutHideWindow` may help.

Comment: It does indeed! Thank you. It obviously pops up briefly before it hides, however. Is there a way to prevent this also? Thank you again.

Comment: Adding `glutInitWindowPosition(8000, 8000);` tells the window to pop up briefly, way off screen,. Solved. Thank you.

Comment: should be easier with other gl contexts than glut